# Disjoint channels in a Hyperledger network

Tags: channel, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

[Channel](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/channels.html) is a mechanism for participants to ensure private and confidential transactions. If channels are created in such a manner where no participant is a member of more than one channel, then what would be the meaning of 'fabric' (or, world) state? Can such a scenario exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a scenario exists all the time. Primarily development, although use cases exist where immutability and provenance are the main requirements and consensus less so. You can still have multiple peers within an Organization (participant) which can provide some level of consensus, etc. But most use cases will have 2 or more Organizations.

To illustrate a bit, just yesterday just for fun I restarted only the orderer. (Doing development so single peer, single orderer, single ca server). My webapp seemed to be creating new records, I could see them as successful in the peer chaincode log and the orderer showed blocks created. But they would not return on a retrieve and I was not getting the final SUCCESS message for the transaction.

The reason was that the peer had lost inbound communication with the orderer, and so was not receiving the new blocks back to put into the world state. I restarted the peer and it reconnected to the orderer and started receiving the world state blocks which the webapp could then retrieve fine. (Same as if the peer had been offline while other peers were updating world state. Immediately on rejoining the orderer it gets all world state blocks since it was offline)

Comment: In your first para of response, isn't immutability and provenance a function of consensus?

Comment: In Hyperledger, yes. But if you only consent with yourself, per your question, then it is 'practically' not real consensus. So because you technically get consensus then you also get the immutability and provenance. Even within an Org, if you had 5 peers, especially if they each had their own real person admins, then you'd have decent consensus and assurance no tampering with the data or the chaincode.

Comment: Agree. Is there a tool that can scan a Hyperledger network and report dis-joints?